# How to Rename all NAs in specific column as a 0 and then drop those rows (0s) across entire dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a dataframe with 50,000 obs of 298 variables, with a column that counts age of people in the survey. I want to exclude everyone who responded 0 (under 15) and NA, as I will be looking at wage related columns in the dataset. If I want to make all the NAs into 0 and then drop all 0s from that column (and remove those rows from the rest of the dataframe), how would I do so?

I have tried to create a copied dataframe (df_2) with all NAs renamed to 0s and then drop those using:

```
df_2$q1 <- ifelse(is.na(df_1$q1), 0, df_1$q1)
df_2[df_2$q1 != 0, ]
```

but this doesn't work

For example this is my beginning dataframe:

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | NA | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| r2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| r3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| r4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| r5 | NA | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I want to get this resulting dataframe:

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| r2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: what to you mean by "drop 0 and NAs from columns" and "drop rows for those 0s and NAs"? Do you mean to filter out rows with 0s or NAs for specific columns?

Comment: You can filter out NAs directly, no need to convert to 0s as an intermediary step. Use `df_2[!is.na(df_2$q1),]`

Comment: It would be much clearer if you'd share a small example of sample input and desired output. Maybe something like `df1 = data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c(0, NA, 3, 4, 5), c = c(1, 0, NA, 4, 0))` What would your desired output be with that input? (Don't reply in comments - edit an example and the desired result into your question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all rows with `NA` or `0` in `col1` with:

```
df_2 = df_1[!df_1$col1 %in% c(NA, 0), ]
```

Or if you prefer `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df_2 = df_1 |> filter(!col1 %in% c(NA, 0))
```

If you'd rather take your two-step approach of converting `NA` to `0` and then dropping 0s, here are base and `dplyr` options:

```
## base
df_2 = df_1
df_2[is.na(df_2$col1), "col1"] = 0
df_2 = df_2[df_2$col1 != 0, ]

## dplyr
df_2 = df_1 |>
  mutate(col1 = coalesce(col1, 0)) |>  ## coalesce replaces NA values
  filter(col1 != 0)
```